# java exception handling in inheritance

Tags: java

just look at program below..

```
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*; 
class class1 
{
 public void m1() throws RemoteException 
{
 System.out.println("m1 in class1"); } }

 class class2 extends class1 
{
  public void m1() throws IOException 
{  
   System.out.println("m1 in class2");

} }

class ExceptionTest2 
 { 
public static void main(String args[])
 {
   class1 obj = new class1();
  try{ 
obj.m1(); 
} catch(RemoteException e){ System.out.println("ioexception"); }

} }
```

compile time error.....can not override m1() method

Now if I replace RemoteException in parent class with IOException and vice versa in child class. Then it is compiling.

Any other checked exception combinations are not working here, evenif I am using checked exception which are at same level.

Now I am confused why overriding is taking place only in one case, not in other cases??? I will realy appreciate your answer.

Comment: You have already posted this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520596/i-am-learning-the-exception-handling-in-java-basically-in-inheritance

Answer (score 5):

`Exceptions` rule in `Inheritance` goes like this:

"When a **subclass overrides** a method in super class then subclass method definition can **only specify all or subset of exceptions classes in the `throws`** clause of the `parent` class method(or overridden method)".

`RemoteException` inherits `IOException`, so `RemoteException` is a child class and `IOEXception` is a superclass. It means the subclass(class2) method that overrides parent class(class1) method, which throws `IOException`, can `throw` `RemoteException` but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

`RemoteException` is more specific than `IOException` so you can declare that the member `m1()` of the inheriting class throws this. (`RemoteException` inherits from `IOException` and thus `RemoteException` is a special kind of `IOException`).

It does not work the other way round: by specifying that *ANY* object of type `class1` throws a `RemoteException` in its member `m1()`, you can't specify that the same method in `class2` throws something more generic (because `class2` type objects are also `class1` type objects).

Answer (score 1):

A RemoteException is an IOEception, but not the other way around. Since class 2 extends class 1, all thrown exceptions must be compatible with the superclass exceptions. When class1.m1 throws an IOException, class2.m1 can throw a RemoteException since that is a specialization of an IOException.

Answer (score 0):

Because two methods with the same signatures cannot throw different kinds of exceptions.