# Exception handling in Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, exception

This is in continuation of question in link:
[I am learning the Exception handling in java (basically in inheritance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520596/i-am-learning-the-exception-handling-in-java-basically-in-inheritance)
that child class method must throw the exception which is subclass of parent class method.

> "When a subclass overrides a method in super class then subclass
>   method definition can only specify all or subset of exceptions classes
>   in the throws clause of the parent class method(or overridden method"

This is a rule. but i am not able to figure out whats the reason behind making this rule, Why vice versa is not allowed. Why this rule is created

Comment: Already answered by Steve McLeod in the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520613/685806

Comment: This question is not answered, the answer above explains the rule but not the reason for the rule which is what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) to work, the [method signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) need to remain the same where expected so that they conform to the same interface.

For example if you have a `Car` which has a method `drive()` which throws `UnknownIgnitionException` and you have a `Ford` that `extends` that class, you will sometimes want to treat it like a car (and not specifically a `Ford` type `Car`) so you would expect the method `drive()` to look and act exactly the same in all cars.

This means if you wanted to test drive a bunch of cars (Ford, Fiat, Porche) you could have

```
 for (Car c : listOfCars) //list contains Fords, Porches, Fiats, etc
 {
   try {
      c.drive(); //All sub-classed Cars contain this exact method 
   }
   catch (UnknownIgnitionException e)
   {
   //As all subclassed cars are restricted to the same method signature, you can be sure what exceptions all Cars throw
   }
 }
```

If they all threw standalone exceptions then you couldn't do this.